# Index для типа Box2d

Tags: postgis

Подскажите класс операторов для создания индекса по типу Box2d в PostGis
Я всё перебрал, ругается: data type box2d has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Answer (score 1):

При создании индекса можно использовать выражения, при условии что такое же выражение потом будет использоваться в запросах.

```
CREATE INDEX bbox_idx ON bbox_tab USING gist (ST_MakePolygon(box_field));
```